# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and dispite properties are set in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

Im having a problem

Spring boot is giving me the following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

dispite adding entries in the application.properties in src/main/resources

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coupons-db
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

these are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

does anybody have a clue why this isnt working

springboot version 2.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: Does the same application work with Spring Boot 2.3.0?

Comment: problem solved ! it wasn't seen the application.properties becuase the project was a POM project (copy past issue :) )